# StackOverflowException was unhandled C#

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

I am getting a odd error that I cant recall ever getting before. I am trying to make a few menus for a small game but somehow something is wrong with my reference to Form1.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form3 Form3 = new Form3();
        public string difficulty = "Makkelijk";
        public string guesses = "Normaal";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Form3.difficulty = difficulty;
            //Form3.guesses = guesses;
            Form3.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void optionsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 Form1 = new Form1();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Woord toevoeg query
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Form1.difficulty = comboBox1.Text;
        //Form1.guesses = comboBox2.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, circular initialization is causing your exception.

One way of solving it is to make Form2 accept Form1 as constructor parameter.

```
Form1 form;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    form = form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are initializing the `Form2` inside the `Form1` and in `Form2` you are initializing `Form1`, which makes circular initialization and causes to stackoverflow exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Form1` in the ctor of `Form2` and `Form2` in the ctor of `Form1`.
Each time you create one of those, you create the other as well and so you get into an infinite loop which evantualy fills up your stack.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of Form1 creates a new Form2. The First line of Form2 creates a new Form1. This will keep happening until you run out of memory.

Remove the

```
Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
```

from the Form2 definition.

Comment: But how do I make refferences to Form1 from form2 then?

Comment: Pass `this` as a parameter to the constructor of form2 when you call it in form1

Comment: Pass in a reference to a Form1 instance to the constructor of Form2. Something like `Form2 form2 = new Form2(ref this);` and the the Form2 constructor would be `public Form2(ref Form1 form1) {this->form1 = form1;}`

Comment: ignore the 'ref' keywords in the line above - they aren't required